# Filter data frame by lowest common overlap in categorical variable in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have the following data frame:

```
input<-data.frame(
site=c("1","2","3","1","2","3","4","1","2"),
year=c(rep("2006",3),rep("2010",4),rep("2014",2)
))

  site year
1    1 2006
2    2 2006
3    3 2006
4    1 2010
5    2 2010
6    3 2010
7    4 2010
8    1 2014
9    2 2014
```

I would like to return a list  of sites surveyed in 2006, 2010, and 2014; so in the example above only site 1 and 2 would be in the list as they are the only sites that were surveyed in 2006, 2010, and 2014.

Any advice is most appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ddply to count the number of years that are in your list of years of interest, for each site and then pull the sites that have all three.

```
library(plyr)

res <- ddply(.data = input, .variables = .(site),
            summarize, allthree = all(c("2006","2010","2014") %in% year))

res$site[res$allthree]
```

Comment: Or to avoid another package dependency, `names(Filter(function(x) x==3, table(input$site)))` would work with the same idea using base functions.

Comment: @MrFlick, any solution that does not use `c(2006, 2010, 2014)` is wrong.

Comment: @flodel If there are no other years in the dataset, it would be fine. There is nothing in the question to indicate that.

Comment: @flodel -- It should work either way, assuming you don't list a site and year twice.

Comment: Why not just answer the question like it was asked, and not make assumptions about the OP's data? That's robust programming.

Comment: @flodel You completely changed that answer with that edit. Shouldn't you just have submitted you own answer? That was not what the original commenter suggested.

Answer (score 2):

If your data may contain other years. This solution should work

```
yearsneeded <- c("2006","2010","2014")
names(which(tapply(input$year, input$site, function(x) all(yearsneeded %in% x))))
```

Answer (score 2):

It may be most straightforward to first cross-tabulate year and site using `table()`, and to then "apply" the function `all` to each of the table's rows to find which ones have all non-zero entries, like so:

```
(tb <- table(input))
#     year
# site 2006 2010 2014
#    1    1    1    1
#    2    1    1    1
#    3    1    1    0
#    4    0    1    0

rownames(tb)[apply(tb,1,all)]
# [1] "1" "2"
```

Or, if you really just care that there should be at least one presence in each of 2006, 2010, and 2014 (even if your data might contain other years), try this:

```
rownames(tb)[apply(tb[,c("2006", "2010", "2014")], 1, all)]
# [1] "1" "2"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is another approach (updated). It also works if the original input data frame has more than the 3 years in the example

```
years <- c(2006,2010,2014) #list with required years
df <- input[input$year %in% years,] #data frame containing only the required years
sites <- as.numeric(which(rowSums(table(df)) == length(years))) #sites that fullfill the criteria
```